# Issues installing mongodb on centos 5

Tags: installation, yum, centos5, mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb for my centos 5.1 server via yum. I followed the instructions of creating a .repo file in the yum folder, but it still doesnt work. here's the screenshot of the issue:

---- http://prntscr.com/41b22y

I typed **yum install mongodb-org** but im getting a "nothing to do" error. I'm not sure what i did wrong. I even did **yum makecache** and still didnt work.

```
#### cat mongodb.repo
    [mongodb]
    name=MongoDB Repository
    baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64
    gpgcheck=0
    enabled=1

    [/etc/yum.repos.d] # yum install mongodb-org
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
    Determining fastest mirrors
    addons                                                                                                         | 1.9 kB     00:00
    base                                                                                                           | 1.1 kB     00:00
    extras                                                                                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00
    mongodb                                                                                                        |  951 B     00:00
    updates                                                                                                        | 1.9 kB     00:00
    wiredtree                                                                                                      |  951 B     00:00
    Excluding Packages in global exclude list
    Finished
    Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
    Finished
    7 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
    Setting up Install Process
    No package mongodb-org available.
    Nothing to do

    [/etc/yum.repos.d] #
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configure the package management system (YUM).

Create a /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo file to hold the following configuration information for the MongoDB repository:

If you are running a `64-bit` system, use the following configuration:

```
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

If you are running a `32-bit` system, which is not recommended for production deployments, use the following configuration:

```
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/i686/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

When you install the packages, you choose whether to install the current release or a previous one. This step provides the commands for both.

To install the latest stable version of MongoDB, issue the following command:

```
sudo yum install mongodb-org
```

To install a specific release of MongoDB, specify each component package individually and append the version number to the package name, as in the following example that installs the 2.6.1` release of MongoDB:

```
yum install mongodb-org-2.6.1 mongodb-org-server-2.6.1 mongodb-org-shell-2.6.1 mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.1 mongodb-org-tools-2.6.1
```

For reference if still stucked with that i found this link,this might be helpful

```
http://serverdown.ttwait.com/que/611667
```

Comment: thank you. i thought it odd that i name it [mongodb] but at command line need to enter sudo yum install mongodb-org (the added -org) held me up for a few

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation site](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/):

/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo

`[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1`

Then

`yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install using their [instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/). You could try disabling the priorities plugin. Set enable = 0.

```
vim /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/priorities.conf
enable = 0
```

Then yum update and then try installing mongodb again.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository configuration seems to be correct, but why are you trying to install mongodb-org? Try installing mongo-10gen-server, that's the package you need.